# How do I set up a ReactiveCocoa 3.0 podspec to be used as a 'private pod' with my test project?

Tags: cocoapods, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I'm learning ReactiveCocoa by using a WORKBENCH project of mine. However, the latest CocoaPod's spec is for version 2.1.8 - and I want to use the ReactiveCocoa 3.0 to go thru the 'learning curve'. I thought of going the route of creating a 'Private CocoaPod' podspec, but it has not worked out for me... (I'm a noob with CocoaPods). Anyway, has anybody done this? is there a bester way? Ideally,  I want to update the ReactiveCocoa 3.0 with Sourcetree as updates are made - just like it works now for version 2.1.8... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) folks have moved away from [CocoaPods](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods) in favor of [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage), primarily because CocoaPods was late to the game supporting Swift and dynamic frameworks -- which is what RAC3 requires. As someone who struggled to get ReactiveCocoa working in an existing project using CocoaPods, I would urge you not to go that route. It's infuriating.

All the info you need to get started with Carthage can be found on [Carthage's github landing page](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage).